# Cakephp 3: Reading a file in the img folder from another file contained in the same folder

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, gd

I'm creating an image using the gd library.
The script creates the image object, then it opens the `logo.png` image and paste it into `$image`.

```
$image = ImageCreate(192,64);
$myFile = imagecreatefrompng('logo.png');
imagecopy($image,$myFile,0,0,0,0,64,64);
ImageDestroy($myFile);
```

This script works fine in another application (with no framework), but here in CakePHP 3, it doesn't work.
The script and the `logo.png` image are located in the `webroot/img` folder of CakePHP.

The script is called this way from the view (template):

```
<img src="/cake/img/kana/makelogo.php">
```

The script crashes with no error message. (Firefox says that the image file can not be displayed because it is corrupted.)

It crashes when the line `$myFile = imagecreatefrompng('logo.png');` is not commented.
Is there special routing settings to allow a script in the img folder to access a file in the img folder?

Answer (score 0):

The image path is relative to the file the code is contained in. If your script is in `weboroot/img/kana` but the image is up a directory in `webroot/img`, it won't be able to find it.

You could specify a relative path instead:

```
 $myFile = imagecreatefrompng('../logo.png');
```

And just FYI if it's ever moved to a CakePHP Controller, use the constant defined in `config/paths.php`:

```
$image = ImageCreate(192,64);
$myFile = imagecreatefrompng( WWW_ROOT.'/img/bricks.png');
imagecopy($image,$myFile,0,0,0,0,64,64);
ImageDestroy($myFile);
```

Comment: I've tried the relative path, but it doesn't work. I'll try to move it to the controller

Answer (score 0):

@ahoffner: It works if I do it in the controller. Here's the code I added to the controller:

```
function displaylogo() {
  $image = ImageCreate(192,64);
  $myFile = imagecreatefrompng(WWW_ROOT.'img/logo.png');
  imagecopy($image,$myFile,0,0,0,0,64,64);
  ImageDestroy($myFile);

  ImagePng ($image);
  $this->autoRender = false;
  $this->response->header('Content-Type: image/png');
  $this->response->type('png');
  $this->response->body($image);
}
```

And in the view:

```
<img src="/cake/<MyController>/displaylogo">
```

This solution works for me.